# Mongoose CastError for non-property schema path

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save a field with a unique, sparse index (phone number) and having some trouble. The model I'm saving definitively does *not* have `phone` as a property, yet I'm getting the error message `Cast to string failed for value "undefined" at path "phone"`.  Am I missing something here? I can't set the value to `null` because that would be counted in a sparse index, and using `delete` vs setting the field to `undefined` seems to make no difference.

The schema I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
...,
phone: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    sparse: true
},
...
```

And the doc I'm trying to say has no phone property when logged.

Comment: I've also tried setting phone to emptystring when the value is undefined, but that doesn't appear to jive with a unique index

Comment: Weird, it worked fine when I tried it with mongoose 3.8.21.

Comment: Yeah I just tried it directly through the console and it worked fine, but for some reason when that field is undefined I get an error...

`{ firstName: 'A',
  lastName: 'B',
  phone: undefined}`

`Cast to string failed for value "undefined" at path "phone"`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out - when the `phone` is undefined, I have to change my update query to use `$unset`. see https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1051